# How fast does the sequence converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

We have the sequence $$a_1=\frac{9}{4} \quad \qquad a_{n+1}=2\frac{a_n^3-a_n^2+1}{3a_n^2-4a_n+1}$$ that converges to $\frac{9}{4}$.

I want to check how fast the convergence is.

Do we have to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}-9/4|}{|a_n-9/4|}$ ?

Comment: How do you define the speed of convergence of a sequence?

Comment: I thought that if the above limit is less than 1 then it converges linearly. Is that notcorrect?@JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: I don't know. It depends upon the definition that *you* are working with.

Comment: The fixed point $f(x)=x$ seems to be $2$ not $\frac 94$.

Comment: @MaryStar in computer science one way to do so is to see if $a_n=O(f(n))$ where $f(n)=n^\epsilon$ or $e^n$...

Comment: Your question about the limit : If the convergence is linear, yes, but if for example the convergence is quadratic, you have to place an exponent $2$ on the denominator...

Comment: @Michelle I think that needs some slight rephrasing if you want to talk about rate of convergence rather than rate of divergence to infinity.

Comment: Let $a_n=2+b_n$, and find the recursion for $b_n$

Comment: hat do we have if we have calculated $b_n$ ? @Empy2

Comment: The sequence converges to $2$ as $n\to\infty$. These are the first $5$ elements of the sequence $$\{2.25,2.03913,2.00117,2.000001,2.,\ldots\}$$ where *Mathematica* approximated $5$th element to $2$ because it's $2.000000000000971$

Comment: We have that $$b_{n+1}=\frac{2a_n(a_n-2)^2}{(3a_n-1)(a_n-1)}$$ right? How does ths help us? @Empy2

Comment: Replace $a_n$ also to get $b_{n+1}=\frac{2{b_n}^2(b_n+2)}{(3b_n+5)(b_n+1)}$ and get $b_{n+1}\sim\frac 45{b_n}^2$ since $b_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Define
$$f(x)=2\frac{x^3 - x^2 + 1}{3 x^2 - 4 x + 1}$$

Prove the sequence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ converge to $2$ with $a_1 =\frac{9}{4}$ as you said.

\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &= f(a_n) \\
&= 2\frac{(a_n-2)((a_n-2)^2+1)}{((a_n-2)+1)(3(a_n-2)+5)} \tag{1}\\
\end{align}

Denote $b_n = a_n-2$, we have $b_n \rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ or $b_n=\mathcal{o}(1)$. And from (1) we have

$$b_{n+1}+2 = f(b_n+2)$$
or
\begin{align}
b_{n+1} &=f(b_n+2)-2 \\
&= \frac{b_n(b_n^2+1)}{(b_n+1)(3b_n+5)} -2 \\
&= \frac{2}{5}b_n(b_n^2+1)(1-b_n+\mathcal{O}(b_n^2))(1-\frac{3}{5}b_n+\mathcal{O}(b_n^2)) -2\\
&= \frac{4}{5}b_n^2-\frac{22}{5}b_n^3+\mathcal{O}(b_n^4)\\
&= \frac{4}{5}b_n^2(1+\mathcal{O}(b_n)) \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
Then,
$$\ln(b_{n+1})= \ln(\frac{4}{5})+ 2\ln(b_{n}) +\ln(1+\mathcal{O}(b_n))  $$
$$\iff (\ln(b_{n+1})-\ln(\frac{4}{5}))=  2(\ln(b_{n})-\ln(\frac{4}{5})) +\mathcal{O}(b_n)  \tag{3}$$
We notice that from (2), we can deduce also that $b_{n+1}=\mathcal{O}(b_n^2)=\mathcal{o}(b_n)$ or $\mathcal{O}(b_{n+1})=\mathcal{o}(b_n)$. So,
$$(3)\iff (\ln(b_{n+1})-\ln(\frac{4}{5})+\mathcal{O}(b_{n+1}))=  2(\ln(b_{n})-\ln(\frac{4}{5})+\mathcal{O}(b_n)) $$
$$\iff \ln(b_{n})-\ln(\frac{4}{5})+\mathcal{O}(b_{n})=  2^{n-1}(\ln(b_{1})-\ln(\frac{4}{5})) =2^{n-1}\ln(\frac{5}{16})  $$
or
$$b_n=\frac{4}{5} \left(\frac{5}{16} \right)^{2^{n-1}}$$
(because $b_n \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ then $\exp(\mathcal{O}(b_{n}))=1$)

**Conclusion:**
$$a_n \approx 2+\frac{4}{5} \left(\frac{5}{16} \right)^{2^{n-1}}$$

Comment: There is a bit of notation abuse on $b_n$ when the $o({b_n}^2)$ term is suddently ignored. You should call it $c_n$ or $B_n$ when going next line with the logarithm relation.

Comment: @zwim: you are right. Now, honestly I have a doubt about my answer :)

Comment: The answer still stands, but I agree it would be painful to justify it fully. Basically $\ln(b_{n+1})=\ln(4/5)+2\ln(b_n)+O(b_n)$ (actually $-11b_n/2$ if we develop the ln) and this $O(b_n)\to 0$ is still very negligible compared to $\ln(b_n)\to-\infty$ so we can ignore it.

Comment: @zwim: I modified the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to find how many terms it takes in order for $|a_n-\frac{9}{4}|<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is some chosen positive constant. For example, how many terms would it take for $a_n-\frac{9}{4}<10^{-3}$?